# javac(compile) and java(run) package work at different directory structure levels?

Tags: java, compilation, classpath, javac

I just noticed that for compiling I need to specify the exact path from my current location for the java source files that needs to be compiled, but to run the class file, all I need is the class qualified name.

Does the `java` command recursively look inside all the folders in my current directory to find the class and execute it?

if so why doesn't the `javac` work similarly but expects to have the absolute path?

From my project folder location,

```
javac -cp ".:/Users/page/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:target/classes" src/main/java/app/Assignment04.java


java -cp ".:/Users/page/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:target/classes" app.Assignment04
```

EDIT:
when I explicitly mentioned path like this;
`java -cp ".:/Users/page/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:src/main/java/com/scg/util/*:src/main/java/com/scg/domain/*:src/main/java/app/*" app.Assignment04`

I get
`Error: Could not find or load main class app.Assignment04`

although I give `src/main/java/app/` in my `classpath`

Answer (score 0):

```
-cp ".:/Users/page/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:target/classes"
```

is the important bit. When compiling the classpath argument is not considered for the source files themselves (only to resolve dependencies).

When running with `java` the named class is sought on the classpath, *which includes the target directory explicitly* as `target/classes`. Thus that location is also used to find the class in question.

Comment: but my class is in `app/assignment.class`

Comment: But your class is `app.assignment,` and the `-cp` argument already told `java` where to look.

Comment: @EJP: I tried a different version which I posted in the edit. if my understanding is correct, I have provided the class file in the `cp`, but it did not work..

Comment: So your version is wrong, isn't it? A classpath entry should be the *head* of a package structure. Not a list of package structures. All you need in your example is one `src/main/java`.

Comment: @EJP: compiling by maven puts all the classes in target folder. but when I compile in command-line, using `javac -cp`, I use the full path to the Java files. There is one and only one `src/main/java`, when I compile using commandline, the class files go into the same package directories..